# Conflicting dependencies of pypyodbc and blpapi

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypyodbc, blpapi

I have a conda environment where I have installed `pypyodbc` and now I am trying to install the `blpapi` package with the following command:

```
conda install -c dsm blpapi
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - blpapi
  - pypyodbc
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

When I have tried running "conda info blpapi" and "conda info pypyodbc", but no dependencies are shown. Why is that? Furthermore, is there another way to find the package dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `pypyodbc` only works with `python` 3x, so my solution was to install `blpapi` for `python` 3x instead of `python` 2x.

I found the dependencies on Anaconda Cloud under each of the different `blpapi` and `pypyodbc` packages.